WPF ItemsPanel with extra controls other than the binding controls
I'm trying to create a custom panel where the user can drag and drop widgets onto a standard WPF grid. Each widget has view model and I have the XAML set up like so:
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WidgetViewModels}">
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <GridWidgetDropper/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <WidgetView DataContext="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Col, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="{Binding RowSpan, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding ColSpan, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>


Here, GridWidgetDroppr is a subclass of Grid.
However I want to add some controls to GridWidgetDropper, like a border that shows a preview of where the widget is going to be dropped. However, WPF clears every control I try to add when it binds to ListBox's Items. If I add the border in code to Grid's Children property it throws an exception because ListBox wants total control of that list.
After doing some research I found out about Panel's InternalChildren property and believed this to be a way to add UIElements without interfering with Children, however this results in the same exception being thrown. I also tried adding it AddVisualChild and AddLogicalChild, but this results in nothing happening on the screen afterwards. So clearly I'm missing something, there has to be a way to add controls to a panel even if the Children property is owned by another control.

"there has to be a way ..." - no, you won't be able to manually modify the Childern collection of the ItemsPanel of an ItemsControl. Modify the source collection, e.g. as shown in the answer to the duplicate question.
